# How to notice bridges easily in Fleury's algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

**Objective**

Find eulerian path

We have a graph and how to notice bridges without removing the edges (I mean only looking on graph because I do this on paper and do not remove the edges)? We start from vertex and go and meet bridges and if we remove edges and vertices ( I mean not all but step by step) we can see easily the bridges but if we do not do this, this became not trivial. I know what bridge is but in practice it is different.

We have for example this graph without purple edge it is semi eulerian

[image]

and we go throughout path and do not remove edges how can we notice the bridge?